# Remmina SSH session logging to file

Tags: ssh, log, remmina

Does there exist an easy way to log the complete content of a SSH session to a file during a Remmina SSH connection?

Comment: Look into the command `script`. It may be possible to use this command as a **Pre-command** in Remmina ssh configuration. I have not tried it, but it works in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

In Remmina version "1.4.25 (git n/a)" there is an option to log ssh output.

- Hit the "New connection profile" button on the top
- Navigate to "Advanced" tab
- Find "Folder for SSH session log", hit the checkbox, choose the folder
- Hit the "Log SSH session asynchronously" checkbox
- You can hit the "Save as Default" button, and newly added connection profile will get this setting, or just the hit "Save" button to save this setting only for this connection profile.
- Done, see print screen attached.
  [Remmina Connection Profile PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soCXy.png)